# How could I write my code for layout such that my layout looks uniform for all android devices?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, android-6.0-marshmallow

For Eg : The following code I've wrote for Button :

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
    android:text="Done"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

and the code for theme which is applied to Button is

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/appTurquoiseColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

The problem is on my device (Coolpad Note3 Lite) having android 6.0 the button is not getting background of  TurquoiseColor which I've applied in theme. Although it is working fine for other devices.how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Your button**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button_submit"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Done"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**Your style**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/appTurquoiseColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

**100% working**

Comment: @Nikhil use style tag of button instead of   android:theme

Comment: I tried both ways by :  Case I : style="AppTheme.Button"  Case II : style="@style/AppTheme.Button" but it didn't work